# Reconciling differences in CI calculated between SAS and R on same dataset

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, sas, lsmeans

I have been given a brief of replicating statistical analysis which was done previously to verify results. Data being collected are body weights of male and female mice over 20 weeks, given a treatment or placebo: (Healthy-Placebo, Healthy-Treated, Diseased-Placebo, Diseased-Treated) across both sexes. The original analysis was done in SAS, and the report stated

> Data from each individual endpoint were analysed using a **linear mixed model for repeated measurements**, with fixed effects **exploring week, sex and treatment group**, and the **interactions amongst those three factors**.  Least squares means, group differences and 95% confidence intervals were reported. P**airwise analysis for apriori defined comparisons** were conducted using **t-tests**, and mean differences, confidence intervals and p values were reported.

So far so good.

I was trying to replicate it in R, as we don't have SAS, and did it like this

```
library(lsmeans)
library(lme4) 
library(multcomp)
library(emmeans)
library(tidyverse)

lmer(Mass ~ Treatment * Sex * Week + (1 | Random), data = Data) %>%
  lsmeans("Treatment", by = c("Sex", "Week")) %>%
  pairs(adjust = "none")  %>%
 confint()
```

This allows me to (almost) replicate the least square means, and mean differences, but not confidence intervals.

[image: Data]

And as the CI of the body mass are different, my t-test CI and p values are also off, by a large amount (as the difference gets compounded I assume).

[image: t-tests]

I am assuming this is becuase SAS and R (defualt) use different ways to calculate CI. Is there any way to correct for this in R? Am I missing something?

PS: The random variable, accounts for individual variablity between mice.

Data: https://pastebin.com/4vdLb248

Comment: I can only guess that the random part of the model differs, because SAS's standard errors are greater. Are you sure there wasn't. another random effect in the SAS model?

Comment: Another possibility is they used a different d.f. method, e.g. containment, which would yield more conservative results than the K-R method used by default in lsmeans().

Comment: @RussLenth 

1) As far as I know, the model has no other random variable... but I don't have access to the SAS model (all I have is the excel sheet in the pictures and the raw data)



2) Interesting observation about the method of df calculation...I'll have to investigate and play around with other packages that allow containment based df... Do you have any suggestions/can you point me in the right direction please?....ls means does not allow you to change it..unless I am missing something very obvious

Comment: The containment method is available in emmeans with nlme::lme models, so that could be something to try. See vignette("models", "emmeans")

Comment: @RussLenth Danke. Passed my data through nlme:lme and then through emmeans. So originally by the KR method I was getting 144 df. By the lme/constraint method, my df is reduced to 97..so that seems to be working -----

However,the CI calculated was somehow the same as the KR method? Am I doing something obviously wrong?---- (lme(Mass~Treatment * Sex * Week, data = Data, random = ~1|Random)

Comment: OK, well I wasn't sure how big the data set is. Could have made a difference if it were a lot smaller, but there is hardly a difference between 97 and 144 df (or infinite df for that matter) in terms of P values and confidence limits.